# "Unexpected symbol `else'" How can I fix this (no semicolon after if-statement)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error at line 56... can someone tell me why?
I haven't put any semicolons at the end of an if statement, and I also used right brackets placement... what is the problem here?
I would appreciate some help, thank you!

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerPrefsManager : MonoBehaviour {

    const string MASTER_VOLUME_KEY = "master_volume";
    const string DIFFICULTY_KEY = "difficulty";
    const string LEVEL_KEY = "level_unlocked_";

    public static void SetMasterVolume(float volume)
    {
        if (volume > 0f && volume < 1f) {

            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat (MASTER_VOLUME_KEY, volume);

        } else {

            Debug.LogError ("Master volume out of range");

        }
    }

    public static float GetMasterVolume()
    {
        return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat (MASTER_VOLUME_KEY);
    }

    public static void UnlockLevel (int level)
    {
        if (level <= Application.levelCount - 1) {

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(LEVEL_KEY + level.ToString(), 1); //Use 1 for true

        } else {
            Debug.LogError("Trying to unlock level that isn't in build settings");
        }
    }

    public static bool IsLevelUnlocked(int level)
    {
        int levelValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt (LEVEL_KEY + level.ToString ());
        bool isLevelUnlocked = (levelValue == 1);

            if (level <= Application.levelCount - 1) {
            {

                return isLevelUnlocked;

            } else {
                Debug.LogError("Trying to unlock level that isn't in build settings");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Assets/Scripts/PlayerPrefsManager.cs(56,30): error CS1525: Unexpected
>   symbol `else'

Comment: Please indicate which line you're getting this error on.

Comment: *I used right brackets placement* - well, not exactly...

Comment: `I am getting an error at line 56.` As a suggestion for next time - it would help if you pointed out which line was line 56.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an extra opening bracket:

```
  if (level <= Application.levelCount - 1) { //here
  { //also here
```

in IsLevelUnlocked()